# RDLC Show/Hide control base on a field value

Tags: report, rdlc

I have rectangle rdlc control and inside it there are several textboxes. The rectangle visibility depends on "Interest" dataset field. If interest value is greater than 0 then display that rectangle else hide.

I tried to set the visibility expression of the rectangle like this

```
=Sum(Fields!Interest.Value, "BasePayment")>0
```

But that's not working. Even if the interest value is greater than zero the rectangle is not showing at all.

Please help. I'm new to RDLC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change your visibility expression to this:

```
=Sum(Fields!Interest.Value, "BasePayment")<=0
```

Comment: Hey buddy I've posted new question about RDLC. I hope you can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354121/rdlc-format-textbox-expression