# RDLC Format Textbox Expression

Tags: report, reporting, rdlc

I have a textbox that should display "interest" value in this format for example "(5%)". The Dataset Interest field has datatype System.Decimal. If I don't format the textbox it just displays "5" on the report page.

Currently in my designer I have

```
Interest «Expr»
```

Then the report page displays

```
Interest 5
```

Back to my problem I want to display something like this

```
Interest (5%)
```

How can I format the Interest expression «Expr»?

Please help. I'm new to RDLC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just concatenate the expression.
For example:

```
="Interest (" & Fields!Interest.Value & "%)"
```